# jQuery mobile ajax load jsonp not work after page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I made a mobile webpage with jQuery Mobile. I load the tweets using jQuery's `.ajax()` method on page load. It works but when I change the page by clicking a link, the tweets won't load anymore.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="c" data-inset="true" id="tweets">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Latest Tweets</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/LicsonLee.json',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data,function(i){
                if(i < 5){
                    var tweet = data[i];
                   $('#tweets').append($('<li/>').html('<a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweet.user.screen_name+'/status/'+tweet.id_str+'" data-rel="external"><h4>'+tweet.text+'</h4><p>at '+tweet.created_at+'</p></a>'));
                 }
            });
            $('#tweets').listview('refresh');
        }
    });
});
```

[The page that has problem](http://serve-licson.net23.net/mobile/)

**Current progress**

I've tried Gajotres' answer but it still worked once only. The pages are loaded through AJAX. I also checked that other pages' HTML structure are correct. I still cannot figure out why this is happened.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Bellow you will find a fix for your problem, I have downloaded your page and tested it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

This should not be used in this case :

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function(){
```

it will trigger only once, instead this should be used:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforeshow',function(){
```

### EDIT :

This should do it:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){
```

If you want to find out more about this take a look at my **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, to be more transparent it is my personal blog. Or it can be found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

### EDIT 2 :

This solution works:

```
$(document).on('pageshow',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/LicsonLee.json',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success:function(data){
            $('#tweets *:not([data-role=list-divider])').remove();
            $.each(data,function(i){
                if(i < 5){
                    var tweet = data[i];
                    $.mobile.activePage.find('#tweets').append($('<li/>').html('<a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweet.user.screen_name+'/status/'+tweet.id_str+'" data-rel="external"><h4>'+tweet.text+'</h4><p>at '+tweet.created_at+'</p></a>'));
                }
            });
            $.mobile.activePage.find('#tweets').listview('refresh');
        }
    });
});
```

Each time you were appending content it was appended to the **`#tweets`** at a first page, this will append it only to the currently active page.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it still work once only.

Comment: try this line: $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){

Comment: Thanks Gajotres! It works. (Before this, I thought the first page has been removed out of the DOM after the page change.)